# What was the death toll of non-Americans in the Vietnam War?

Tags: war, vietnam-war

How many Vietnamese and Cambodians were killed in the Vietnam war? How many civilians, and how many soldiers? What are the best sources on this question?

Comment: documents like these: http://www.soc.washington.edu/users/brines/vietcasualties.pdf

Comment: I'm guessing you also don't want to count French, who were fighting there long before the Americans were. Do you want to count SE asian deaths from the French period in the conflict?

Comment: I'm mostly interested in the American stage of the conflict...but would be interested in all good data on this...

Comment: @T.E.D. and fraxture ... and the hundreds of Autralians killed?

Answer (score 2):

882,000 Vietnamese casualties, of whom about 444,000 were soldiers, and 200,000–300,000 Cambodian casualties, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnam_War_casualties).

And, in addition, it is estimated that as many as 210,000 soldiers and civilians, from an assortment of other nations, primarily Laos, were also killed.

Comment: And, in addition ...

Comment: any more authoritative source than Wikipedia?